# Create two iOS Apps in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, projects

Using Xcode (to develop on iOS) I want to create a second project that it is the same as a first project but some classes are differents.

Exactly, I'm creating an IPhone App and I want to offer a free version and a premium version. Actually, the code of the projects are identical but changes some classes.

The problem is I don't want support two projects. If I modify a class, then I have to modify the same change on the other project. It is very redundant.

Besides, the project are pushed to a remote GIT respository.

And one last note, an iOS App is identify using an ID associated with the project.

So, I need two differents projects?

Which is the best solution to create two iOS App projects in Xcode sharing the classes, but changing two o three classes?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I want to offer a free version and a premium version.

In this case, you do not need to create two apps in two projects: all you need is a second *target* for your premium version. Here is a [link that explains how to create and manage multiple targets in Xcode](http://blog.just2us.com/2009/07/tutorial-creating-multiple-targets-for-xcode-iphone-projects/).

The process boils down to adding a target to the project, defining a separate properties plist for it, optionally setting up a preprocessor symbol for conditional compile, and using that symbol to `#ifdef` portions of your classes not needed in the free version.

Another common approach to managing free vs. premium offering is to provide a single version for free, and let users upgrade it to premium through an in-app purchase.

Answer (score 6):

You just have to create two targets. So you'll only modify a single code base, perfect!

[This tutorial](http://blog.just2us.com/2009/07/tutorial-creating-multiple-targets-for-xcode-iphone-projects/) will walk you through (and even uses lite/paid versions as it's example).

Answer (score 0):

1. duplicate target of paid version and name it free version
2. define macro name `PaidApp=1` in paid target, then put this line of code in starting of applicationDidfinishLaunching.

   ```
   #ifdef PaidApp
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:1 forKey:@"adDisabled"];
   #endif
   ```
3. when free app running target, if someone purchase paid app feature then set value of @"adDisabled" to 1 (by default value of @"adDisabled" will be 0)