# How to submit an app that would be free for iPhone and paid for iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

I want to submit an app to App Store.
I want my app to be free for iPhone and paid for iPad.
I couldn't find anywhere in iTunes connect where to set a different price tier for iPhone and iPad.
Would I have to create two different apps in iTunes connect for that purpose?

Comment: it's for same app or different?

Comment: same app. (universal storyboard...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to create two separate apps. There's currently no way you can have different prices for the same app and you can't enable iPad support as, say, an in-app purchase.

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot set 2 different prices (well, free and some price) for the same app.

So you need to create 2 different apps in the AppStore.

You should use 2 distinct targets in Xcode in order to avoid code duplication. More details here: [Create two iOS Apps in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019835/create-two-ios-apps-in-xcode)