# create a light version of a completed app by using target

Tags: ios, app-store, target

I already finished an app, this is a big app that contained multiple parts. Now I want to create a very light version of this app. 
Of course I can create a new project and just copy the codes from the the original version to the new one. 
But I think, if there is a bug in the original version, then I should debug it in the both version, which is not that cool. 
Is there any way, maybe using a new target in the original app project, that I can use the same module of the original app in the light version?

I mean, if I use a new target in my old project, I can send it to App store as a completely different app.

Comment: That's the wrong approach. You should only have one app. In your case it would be a free app with limited functionality. Using in-app purchases, the user can upgrade the functionality. No need for a free "lite" app and a paid "full" app. Apple will likely reject the 2nd app anyway and tell you to have just one with IAP.

Comment: Thanks, but if I want to do it, It's better that I create a new project? or using a target?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create two iOS Apps in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019835/create-two-ios-apps-in-xcode)